# teamcity and docker integration

Tags: teamcity, docker

Has anyone used Teamcity's artifacts in a new build for docker? What I'd like to automate is take the artifacts produced by teamcity, and then create a new docker image with those artifacts.  I couldn't really find any tutorials online.  I saw that Docker could integrate with bitbucket and github, but I wasn't really sure if that was the same thing.  My base image should have mono and a few other things installed.  Installing mono is not part of my source so I wasn't sure if the github integration would work.

Answer (score 2):

Docker can copy an artifact from a remote URL ( https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add ) and TeamCity exposes URL patterns that you can use to download build artifacts from outside TeamCity ( https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts ). If you combine those two, you can create a Docker file that creates a new image with the given artifact.

Like this:

```
ADD http://localhost:8111/guestAuth/repository/download/BuildName/latest.lastSuccessful/artifactName.war /opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with teamcity but in general this should be possible. You should first create a base image with everything you need lets call it "crystal/base".

The in your teamcity setup generate your artifact.
In the same directory as the artifact add a Dockerfile with the following:

```
from crystal/base
ADD artifactFile /var/location_inside_container/artifactFile
CMD ["commandToUserArtifact.sh"]
```

Lastly, build you new docker container with

```
docker build -t crystal/dependent .
```